# iOS: Can't set navigation bar tint color

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

Here is a n00b question, but one I can't seem to solve reading my books and notes:

I'm implementing a navigation control, and I can't figure out why my code is failing to set a tint color for it.

In my app delegate implementation file, under `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method:

```
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    rootViewController *rootView = [[rootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"rootViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootView];
    self.navController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:20/255 green:44/255 blue:86/255 alpha:1];
```

The `navController` initializes just fine but with a black color.

Comment: isnt `alpha:1` fully transparent?

Comment: No, alpha of one is fully lit.  Alpha of 0 is fully transparent.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're seeing a black nav bar because `[UIColor colorWithRed:20/255 green:44/255 blue:86/255 alpha:1]` is black!

You're performing integer division so `20/255 == 0`. Express those values as floats and you should see the color you expected:

`[UIColor colorWithRed:20.0/255 green:44.0/255 blue:86.0/255 alpha:1]`

Comment: I'll be damned. Thanks! Didn't realize there was a difference between 20 and 20.0.

Answer (score 3):

This is black color, because you divide integers.

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:20/255 green:44/255 blue:86/255 alpha:1];
```

Try this:

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:20.0f/255.0f green:44.0f/255.0f blue:86.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
```

Answer (score 1):

(Most of )the tint colors only work on iOS 5.0+ (read the class reference:) )

Comment: Yea, I am running the iPhone 5.0 simulator

Answer (score 1):

for ios 8.0

```
 self.navController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:20/255 green:44/255 blue:86/255 alpha:1];
```